# Django convert model objects to dictionary in large volumes results in server timeout

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have been having a problem where a Django server takes forever to return a response. When running with gunicorn in Heroku I get a timeout, so can't receive the response. If I run locally, it takes a while, but after some time it correctly shows the site.

Basically I have two models:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    #Some stuff charFields, foreignKey, TextField and ManyToMany fields
    #Eg of m2m field:
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    def getTags(self):
        ret = []
        for tag in self.tags.all():
            ret.append(getattr(tag, "name"))
        return ret

    def convertToDict(self):
        #for the many to many field I run the getter
        return {'id': self.id, 'tags' : self.getTags(), ... all the other fields ... }

class EntryState(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def convertToDict(self):
        temp = self.entry.convertToDict()
        temp['field1'] = self.field1
        temp['field2'] = self.field1 + self.field3
        return temp
```

Then I have a view:

```
def myView(request):
    entries = list(EntryState.objects.filter(field1 < 10))

    dictData = {'entries' : []}
    for entry in entries:
        dictData['entries'].append(entry.convertToDict())

    context = {'dictData': dictData}
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

The way it was done, the `dictData` contains the information for all the entries that must be shown in the site. Then, this variable gets loaded into a javascript that will decide how to display the information.

The view gets stuck in the for loop when there's lots of entries with `field1 < 10`.

I was just wondering, what can be done to improve this approach. With +600 entries it already takes forever, enough for `gunicorn` to timeout.

In case it is relevant, I am using Django 4.0.3 and Python3. The data is used in the frontend by Alpine.js to render the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, your main problem is most likely you're hitting the database twice for each EntryState instance.

`convertToDict` method makes use of FK `entry` and for each entry, you also fetch the M2M `tags`. Solution is to optimize the query.

First, let's identify the problem.
When you put this code before the end of the view, you'll see how many times you're hitting the database in the console.

```
def myView(request):
    ....
    from django.db import connection; qq=connection.queries; print(f'QUERY: {len(qq)}')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Now, try to improve the query in the view.

```
query = EntryState.objects.filter(field1 < 10)  # Assuming this is a valid query that uses something like `field1__lt=10`
```

You can use `select_related` for the Entry FK so that it'll be retrieved within that single query (Saves N hits to the DB)

```
query = EntryState.objects.filter(field1__lt=10).select_related('entry')
```

Also you can add prefetch related to retrieve the `tags` for ALL entries in one hit.

```
query = EntryState.objects.filter(field1__lt=10).select_related('entry').prefetch_related('entry__tags_set')
```

After each change, you can see how many times you hit to the database so that you can see the problem getting fixed. You can check the number of DB hits again to ensure it's optimized.

For more info, please read about query optimization, `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

You can also use some apps to monitor the performance of your views: [django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk), [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: This is perfect and reduces the whole call to literally just 4-5 seconds (from 2016 queries to 8). Of course, I still need to be careful in case there were 2000000 entries, and limit it somehow. But for now, this is what I needed.

Comment: For that, you have to use the pagination which will limit the size of the response. Of course it requires a bit of JS skills to fetch the data WHEN you need and how much you need. Number of queries doesn't matter if you're returning a lot of data (and I must say, 4-5 seconds for an endpoint is mostly not acceptable). Anyway, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to render a template containing huge amounts of data.

In this case I think you should consider splitting the data you send into template and entries as two different request types. Meaning you send the template, and then your alpine.js loads the entries one by one. (Edit: I mean in packages of 50 or so, please don't make a request for each entry...)

For this you can use either a ready made [REST Framework Application](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework#overview) for django or deploy your own solution.

Of course that way the user will not see any data after loading the template. Instead they will have to wait for the second request.
The advanced solution to this is rendering only the first 100 entries or so which the user will see, and use your new REST API for the remaining data. You could use the lazy loading alpine.js plugin [Intersect](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/intersect), it will help your performance overall aswell!

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, but what if the entries should be shuffled? So they shouldnt be displayed in the same order? The only way I see it is to get all the info before loading the page and shuffling it in the frontend. But in that case, won't the cost be bigger?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Like the entries are shuffled on each page request?
Or only when the user clicks some button?

Either way the solution stays the same, or at least similar.

You could:
Send a list of entry identifiers with the template, have the frontend shuffle those and then send a bulge request for the shuffled sections.